# Перемещение блока после загрузки страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как вернуть блок в исходное положение после загрузки страницы, если условие не срабатывает?

```
function windowSize() {
    if ($(window).width() <= '767') {
        $("#cart").appendTo("#mobile-cart");
    }
}
$(window).on('load resize', windowSize);
```

То есть если увеличить ширину окна браузера, то `#cart` нужно убрать из `#mobile-cart` и вернуть на исходную в `.header-cart`.

Comment: Быть может, с помощью `else { $("#cart").appendTo(".header-cart"); }`?

Comment: Да то что нужно, самое главное писал тоже самое но забыл поставить фигурные скобки для else.

Comment: Если в `else` одно выражение, то фигурные скобки не являются обязательными. `else $("#cart").appendTo(".header-cart");` равносильно `else { $("#cart").appendTo(".header-cart"); }`.

Answer (score 1):

```
function windowSize() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        $("#cart").appendTo("#mobile-cart");
        $(".header-cart #cart").detach();
    } else {
        $("#cart").appendTo(".header-cart");
        $("#mobile-cart #cart").detach();
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем в коде указаны `.detach()`?

Comment: Что-то тут не то. Тогда уж сначала `detach`, потом `appendTo` для него.

Comment: @Qwertiy `detach` здесь вообще лишний.